# ELIMINACIÓN POR CASCADA, SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

estoy modificando mi base de datos para poder eliminar en cascada.
En la BD, tengo 3 apartados principales **Categorías -> Subcategorias -> Posts**

Me aparece un error al introducir la base de datos en el phpmyadmin, Esta en las 2 linias de **ALTER TABLE**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO**

```
    CREATE TABLE categories(
id                  int(255) auto_increment not null,
name                varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
created_at           datetime DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at           datetime DEFAULT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  pk_users PRIMARY KEY(id),
ALTER TABLE categories ADD CONSTRAINT fk_category_id FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES sub_categories(category_id) ON DELETE
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE sub_categories(
id                  int(255) auto_increment not null,
name                varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
category_id         int(255) NOT NULL,
created_at           datetime DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at           datetime DEFAULT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  pk_users PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT  fk_post_category FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id),
ALTER TABLE sub_categories ADD CONSTRAINT fk_sub_category_id FOREIGN KEY (sub_category_id) REFERENCES posts(sub_category_id) ON DELETE
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE posts(
id                  int(255) auto_increment not null,
sub_category_id     int(255) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: El código que pusiste no coincide con el código donde te marca error, ¿dónde está la tabla `users`? Como sea, creo que el problema en tu tabla `users` es que la coma que está antes de `on delete cascade` no debería ir ahí...

Comment: Pon los `CREATE TABLE` como los tienes, el código de la pregunta está incompleto, es imposible revisarlo así.